# Vertical alignment of lrbox with minipage inside

Tags: lists, boxes

I'm trying to make an environment that prints highlighted notes, and I can't get the vertical alignment right.  Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\makeatletter%
\newenvironment{note}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-7pt}%
      \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}%
      \textbf{Note.}}%
    {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \colorbox{shadecolor}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}%
}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{note}
    This alignment is what I want.

    The top lines up with the number. 
  \end{note}

\item
  \begin{note}
    But if there's a list in the note, the number instead matches up
    with the first item. 

    \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \end{itemize}
  \end{note}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: example]

I'd like the highlighted box to be top-aligned with the enumerate numbers to the left; the first one is fine, but the second one is using the first item of the itemize instead.  What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtle problem. You see that not only the box is displaced, but also the item number.

One should never say `\item \colorbox{color}{text}`, but always

```
\item \leavevmode\colorbox{color}{text}
```

because of funny interactions of color setting and `\item`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\newsavebox{\notebox}
\newenvironment{note}
 {\leavevmode
  \begin{lrbox}{\notebox}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}%
  \textbf{Note.} \ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \colorbox{shadecolor}{\usebox{\notebox}}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{note}
    This alignment is what I want.

    The top lines up with the number. 
  \end{note}

\item
  \begin{note}
    But if there's a list in the note, the number instead matches up
    with the first item. 

    \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \end{itemize}
  \end{note}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I'd avoid using `\@tempboxa`, preferring a new box register. I made also a couple of adjustments. I'd also avoid setting `\parskip`.

Basically, what happens is that processing `\item` is unfinished and the inner `\item` takes over.

[image]